# How to prove orbit periodicity in some conservative systems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, implicit-differentiation

Good afternoon, 
I have some trouble proving periodicity with a conservative system. The problems is that I don't know how to make a formal demonstration although I can see it quite true.

I have the following system: 
$$\frac{dx}{dt}= y \\
\frac{dy}{dt}= -g(x)$$

We know that g is a strictly increasing function.

And $g(0)=0$ , $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int^{x}_{0}g(u)du = \infty$

Doing some algebra it is clear that the phase path are given by:
$$y=\pm[2(C-V(x))]^{1/2}$$

where $V(x)=\int^{x}_{0} g(u)du$

With the help of the information of $g$ we can see that the phase path must look like ovals.
So the orbits are closed paths, and so we can say that orbits are periodic.

But how can I prove this ? I was thinking in giving a diffeomorphism from the path to the circle but I cant find it.

Thanks for you help and your time.

Comment: It occurs to me, although it's just and idea, that from the properties of $g(x)$ you could write the second equation as $\dot y=x+O(x^2)$. And then, at least locally, you have periodic orbits ... ¿? Another idea is, can you use a Poincarè section and prove the existence of a fixed point?

Comment: I still in infacy in this matters, but what I can prove is that the only point of stability is the (0,0). What i'm thinking is to use to propose a solution of the form: $\phi(t)$

$$t-t_0=\int^{\phi(t)}_{x_0}[2(C−V(x))]^{-1/2}dx$$

and see what can I have xD.